# function for nCk chose k elements from list of n in python

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

I'm trying to write a function that makes nCk from the list in python

for example from the list for pairs:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

output should be:

```
[['a','b'],['a','c'],['b','c']]
```

however I'm getting no output

here's my attempt:

```
def chose(elements, k):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        if k == 1:
            output.append(elements[i])
        for c in chose(elements[i+1:], k-1):
            output.append(elements[i])
            output.append(c)
    return output
print chose(['a', 'b', 'c'],2)
```

can you kindly tell what is wrong with function

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254094/question-that-can-be-solved-using-basic-debugging. Reading http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is recommended.

Comment: Also take a look on: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` if you want to find all combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
result = [list(i) for i in combinations(a,2)]
```

The documentation and implementation of the `combinations()` function can be found on [here ...](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

**Update**
This function should do what you want:

```
def chose(elements, k):
    output = []
    if k == 1:
        return [[i] for i in elements]
    else:
        for i in range(len(elements)):
            head = elements[i]
            tails = chose(elements[i+1:], k-1)
            output += [[head] + tail for tail in tails]
        return output

print chose(['a','b','c'], 2)
```

Comment: we are not allowed to use libs unfortunately :|

Comment: Look up the implementation of `iterfunction.combination()` on the link that i posted. You can copy it, if you're not allowed to use libs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a powerset without using any imports:

```
def power_set(items,k):
    n = len(items)
    for i in xrange(2**n):
        combo = []
        for j in xrange(n):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        if len(combo) == k:
            yield combo

print(list(power_set(['a', 'b', 'c'],2)))

[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```